# IEnumerable IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I don't know why I'm getting `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'` with this code

```
IEnumerable<char> query = "Text result";
string illegals = "abcet";

for (int i = 0; i < illegals.Length; i++)
{
    query = query.Where(c => c != illegals[i]);
}

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.Write(item);
}
```

Please can someone explain what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Better like this: *var query = query.Where(c=> !illegals.Contains(c));* just replace your loop with it.

Comment: @eocron: Yup, I'd just added that as a fifth option before I saw your comment :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that your lambda expression is *capturing* the variable `i`, but the delegate isn't being *executed* until after the loop. By the time the expression `c != illegals[i]` is executed, `i` is `illegals.Length`, because that's the final value of `i`. It's important to understand that lambda expressions capture variables, rather than "the values of those variables at the point of the lambda expression being converted into a delegate".

Here are five ways of fixing your code:

**Option 1: local copy of i**

Copy the value of `i` into a local variable within the loop, so that each iteration of the loop captures a new variable in the lambda expression. That new variable isn't changed by the rest of the execution of the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < illegals.Length; i++)
{
    int copy = i;
    query = query.Where(c => c != illegals[copy]);
}
```

**Option 2: extract illegals[i] outside the lambda expression**

Extract the value of `illegals[i]` in the loop (outside the lambda expression) and use that value in the lambda expression. Again, the changing value of `i` doesn't affect the variable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < illegals.Length; i++)
{
    char illegal = illegals[i];
    query = query.Where(c => c != illegal);
}
```

**Option 3: use a foreach loop**

This option only works properly with C# 5 and later compilers, as the meaning of `foreach` changed (for the better) in C# 5.

```
foreach (char illegal in illegals)
{
    query = query.Where(c => c != illegal);
}
```

**Option 4: use `Except` once**

LINQ provides a method to perform set exclusion: `Except`. This is *not* quite the same as the earlier options though, as you'll only get a *single* copy of any particular character in your output. So if `e` wasn't in `illegals`, you'd get a result of "Tex resul" with the above options, but "Tex rsul" using `Except`. Still, it's worth knowing about:

```
// Replace the loop entirely with this
query = query.Except(illegals);
```

**Option 5: Use `Contains` once**

You can call `Where` once, with a lambda expression that calls `Contains`:

```
// Replace the loop entirely with this
query = query.Where(c => !illegals.Contains(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because, although your `for` loop seems at first glance to be correctly bounded, each iteration captures the index in the closure that is passed to `Where`.  one of the most useful properties of closures is that they capture by reference, enabling all sorts of powerful and sophisticated techniques. However, in this case it means that, by the time the query is executed in the ensuing `foreach` loop. The index has been incremented past the length of the array.

The most straightforward change to fix this is create a loop scoped copy the current value of the index loop control variable and refer to this in your closure instead of referring directly to the loop control variable.

Ex:

```
for (int i = 0; i < illegals.Length; i++)
{
    var index = i;
    query = query.Where(c => c != illegals[index]);
}
```

However, as has been noted by others, there are better ways to write this that void the problem entirely and they also have the virtue that they raise the level of abstraction.

For example, you can use `System.Linq.Enumerable.Except`

```
var legals = query.Except(illegals);
```